# What is the alternative to Collections.unmodifiable map for concurrent access to unmodifiable Map

Tags: java, multithreading

With the deprecation of `edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.Collections.unmodifiableMap`, what is the alternative for concurrent access to UnmodifiableMaps?

Comment: Err, `java.util.Collections.unmodifiableMap()`? But if it's read-only there is no concurrency issue to solve.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to protect an UnmodifiableMap (or any [immutable object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) for that matter) against concurrent access.

That's the whole point of immutability.

Answer (score 1):

## `Collections.unmodifiableMap` returns a view onto original map, not a copy

[`java.util.Collections.unmodifiableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap(java.util.Map)) is not deprecated.

As for concurrent access to the map, you have no issue if using the refeference returned by this method. But beware: the returned reference is a view nack onto the original map. So if the original map is changing while you are utilizing the unmodifiable view, you will have concurrency problems.

## `Map.copyOf`

I suggest instead that in Java 10 and later you instead call [`Map.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#copyOf(java.util.Map)). This method makes an actual copy of the map rather than a view. So the result is unrelated to the original. Adding or removing entries in the original map has no effect on the non-modifiable map returned by this method.

```
Map< DayOfWeek , Person > map = new HashMap<>() ;
…
Map< DayOfWeek , Person > mapUnmod = Map.copyOf( fix
```